# C++, препроцессор, условная компиляция и ODR

Tags: c++, inline

Я провожу небольшое исследование существующих способов нарушить `ODR` (`Правило Единого Определения`) при использовании `inline`, и меня интересует следующее.

1. У меня есть некоторые сомнения в том, в какой последовательности происходит препроцессинг и условная компиляция. Например, `include` и `ifdef`. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет уточнить этот момент.
2. Можно ли нарушить `ODR` при использовании условной компиляции в `inline` функциях/методах?

   Например:

   **func.hpp**:

   ```
   inline void func()
   {
       // ...
   #ifdef X
       // ...
   #endif
       // ...
   }
   ```

   **a.cpp**:

   ```
   #define X
   #include "func.hpp"

   void a_func()
   {
       func();
   }
   ```

   **b.cpp**:

   ```
   #undef X
   #include "func.hpp"

   void b_func()
   {
       func();
   }
   ```

   Я полагаю, что сначала происходит подстановка содержимого файла (в месте`include`), а уже потом - условная компиляция. Следовательно, данный код нарушает `ODR` и приводит к неопределенному поведению. Все происходит именно так?
3. Можно ли избавиться от нарушения `ODR`, если `define` и `include` поменять местами?

Comment: Препроцессор работает отдельно от компилятора. Есть определенные опции у компилятора - что он отдаёт код без препроцессора - так вот, нужно написать так, что б код после препроцессора  (без препроцессора) был валидным - и всё.

Comment: Функции будут разными, но про нарушение ODR я не уверен. А ещё можно функции static приписать.

Comment: Касательно тела функции, я так понял, вы хотите сделать две версии, одну с чисто обьявлениями, а другую с реализацией? Тогда его (тела функции) или не должно быть вообще (т.е. скобки { } должны отсутствовать, и в конце точка с запятой), или должно быть полное, поэтому я бы { } внес вовнутрь #if

Comment: @nick_n_a, я хочу понять, что будет, если в разных `*.cpp` окажутся функции с одинаковой сигнатурой (после искажения имен), но с отличающимися телами.

Comment: @Qwertiy Со static, нарушения ODR как раз не будет. (Будет две разных функции, а не два варианта реализации одной.)

Comment: @MGNeo на разные или одинаковые тела к одной сигнатуре - получите ошибку `function body allready defined` или что-то похожее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это если следовать классической схеме - `объявление + определение`. В рамках использования `inline` сообщения об ошибке не произойдет, потому что никакого объявления нет, есть только дублирующиеся определения. Линкер будет считать, что функции одинаковы, потому что он проверяет только сигнатуру, но не тело.

Comment: @Chorkov, так я для того и предложил.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Я так понимаю, вопрос в том, видно ли в заголовочных файлах макросы, определенные в тех файлах, которые эти заголовки включают? Да, конечно видно. Иначе, например, include guard'ы бы не работали.

В вашем примере, `#define X` в `a.cpp` влияет на `#ifdef X` в `func.hpp`. (Конечно, если `#define X` находится выше `#include "func.hpp"`)

**2.** Да, тут ODR нарушен.

**3.** Да, это уберет нарушение ODR, потому что функции станут одинаковыми. `#ifdef X` будет обработан раньше, чем `#define X`.

Comment: Спасибо за четкий ответ.